# Scale figure inside tikzfigure environment in tikzposter class

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikzposter

I am trying to make my poster with the `tikzposter` class.
I want to place a figure inside a block and I have to use the `tikzpicture` environment. But I can't scale the figure properly.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape]{tikzposter}
\begin{document}
  \begin{columns}
     \column{0.25}
     \block{Introduction}{
       ...blabla...
      }
     \column{0.5}
     \block{Methods}{
       \begin{tikzfigure}
         \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{myfigure}
       \end{tikzfigure}
      }
     \column{0.25}
     \block{Results \& conclusions}{
       ...blabla...
      }
   \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

It appears that `\columnwidth` applies to the entire poster width and not to the column I am in, because my image spans the whole poster width.
I don't like using pts or cms as width in `\includegraphics', I would like to use some relative measure. how can I do that inside tikzfigure?

Comment: Probably you should try `\blockwidth` instead?

Comment: @JMP This is not a beamer class and, unfortunately, there is no `\blockwidth` (it is undefined)

Comment: Strange, I can't get it running too, even though the tikzposter manual states: _`\blockwidth`, `\blockbodyheight`, `\blocktitleheight` : Dimensions of the current block's components; it is redefined for each call to the `\block` command._

Comment: Hey you're right, I didn't see that in the manual at first. Does not work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't access the defined widths of the blocks properly, but you can use `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{columns}
     \column{0.25}
     \block{Introduction}{
       ...blabla...
      }
     \column{0.5}
     \block{Methods}{
       \begin{tikzfigure}%
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,draft]{Temp.png}%
       \end{tikzfigure}
      }
     \column{0.25}
     \block{Results \& conclusions}{
       ...blabla...
      }
   \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx! I just found out that `\linewidth` works as well. `\columnwidth` and `\textwidth` do not though

Comment: You're right, `\linewidth` seems to be the better way. I changed the answer to incorporate `\linewidth`